# Sweetalert2 doesn't return true/false

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm trying to work with the SweetAlert2. It works, when I don't want to send some data through $_POST. But when I want to send data through $_POST, the sweetalert just appears on less then one second, then disappers and regardless of user choice the form is send.

How can I modify my code, when I'd like to have a regular window-confirmation and when the user click on "delete", the form will be send, otherways when he click on "cancel", the form will be not send?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {  
  echo 'Your form was submitted.';
}

<form action="#" method="post>                
 <label>
   <span>Username</span>
   <input type="text" value="" name="username" />
 </label>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register!" id="test-1" />    
</label>     
</form>



<script>
 document.querySelector('#test-1').onclick = function(){
  swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
  }).then(function () {
    swal(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
      )
  })

     //IF SWAL => DELETE -> send form
     //ELSE IF SWAL => CANCEL -> do nothing 
     //when I put here "return false;", then sweetalert is working, but it doesn't send the form
</script>
```

## Solution thanks to Novice:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['send']))
{echo 'Your form was submitted.';} ?>

<form id='myfrm' action="#" method="post">   
 <label>
   <span>Username</span>
   <input type="text" value="" name="username" />
   <input type="hidden" name="send" value="send">
 </label>
</form>
 <button value="Register!" id="test-1"> submit </button>

<script>
document.querySelector("#test-1").onclick = function(){
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
    cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
  }).then(function () {
   document.querySelector("#myfrm").submit();    
  })
}      
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using handler you can use handler on form , much better that way

Give form an `id` also change your `submit` button to a normal button coz we will submit(or not submit) manually depending on user's choice

```
<form id='myfrm' action="#" method="post">    <!-- u missed quote here -->            
 <label>
   <span>Username</span>
   <input type="text" value="" name="username" />
 </label>
 <!-- EDIT : removed (not working)
 <input type="button" name="submit" value="Register!" id="test-1" />    
-->
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</label>     
</form>
<!-- EDIT : added -->
<button name="submit" value="Register!" id="test-1"> submit </button>



<script>
 document.querySelector('#test-1').onclick = function(){
  swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
  }).then(function () {

     // swal( 'Ready?!', 'Your form is going to be submitted.' 'success');
     // if you want to show alert that form is going to submit you may un-comment above line
    document.querySelector('#myfrm').submit(); // manully submit 
  })
```

Comment: Thank you, Novice! But still it does not work (or just from the part - it succesfully asks user, if he want to delete it; but the second part in .then(function() doesn't work): http://avcr1.chudst.cz/test.php.

Comment: You might be using an older version of sa2 or sa1 where they use callback function in options so promise based (then()) syntax isn't available in those versions See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mmw6azgh/)  how it should work on the latest version

Comment: I think, I'm using the last version (6.2.0). And you're correct, the "alert" is ok, so the problem is not in the ".then (function()", but directly in "document.querySelector('#myfrm').submit();" - the form is still not sending data.

Comment: Did you give `action` value?

Comment: No, because I've the if(isset($_POST['submit']){} on the same page, so I left action value 'set' on #.

Comment: Finally solved the issue change ,<input type='button'> to <button> and move that outside the form http://jsfiddle.net/mmw6azgh/5

Comment: You're the best, thank you, I really appreciate your efforts - but still I've no idea, what I'm doing wrong: avcr1.chudst.cz/test.php . I've the same code as you do, except the isset($_POST). It appears, the page is reloaded, but the $_POST['submit'] is not sending.

Comment: Hehe thnx .Regarding your issue- `$_POST['submit']` isn't getting set it's bcoz there isn't any item with that name **inside the form - only stuff that is inside the form gets sent** (my mistake) so you'd need to add a hidden item like `<input type="hidden" value="submit" name="submit" />` inside the form and rename `<button name="submit" ......` to something different `<button name="justforsubmit" ......`